# Sympy Simplification with Square Root

Tags: python, sympy, simplify

I have an expression that I think could be simplified somewhat and for some reason sympy is not performing what I think are simple simplifications.  My code with the example is as follows:

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:

from __future__ import division
from sympy import *
init_printing()

# In[3]:

d, R, c = symbols('d R c', Positive = True, Real = True)
Δt = symbols('\Delta_t', Real = True)

# In[4]:

Δt = (1/c**2)*(-R*c+sqrt(c**2*(R+d)**2))
Δt

# In[5]:

simplify(Δt)
```

I have placed the code above for cut and paste pleasures...  The graphical output from iPython is as follows:

[image]

I would have expected the final result to be the following:

[image]

I thought that based on how I defined the variables the simplifications would have happened, at least the sqrt((R+d)**2)...  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I specified that when I created the variables (Positive = True, Real = True).  At least I thought that is what I was doing when I added those options...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try `real = True` and `positive = True` (lower case):

```
import sympy as sp

d, R, c = sp.symbols('d R c', positive = True, real = True)
dt = sp.symbols('\Delta_t', real = True)

dt = (1/c**2)*(-R*c+sp.sqrt(c**2*(R+d)**2))

print(sp.simplify(dt))
```

Output:

```
d/c
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @user5402's answer, SymPy only does simplifications that are valid for general complex numbers by default. In particular, `sqrt(x**2) = x` is not true in general. It is true if `x` is positive. Setting `x` as `Symbol('x', positive=True)` tells SymPy that this is the case.

Comment: Do you know why the same thing doesn't work out when using parse_expr? Doing x = symbols('x', positive = True, real = True) and expr = simplify(parse_expr("sqrt(x**2)")) returns "sqrt(x**2)" instead of "x".

Comment: `parse_expr` creates new symbols. If you want it to reuse an `x` that you defined before, you need to use  `parse_expr('sqrt(x**2), locals())`.