# Equivalent mathematical symbolic expressions are not equal in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to debug (and understand) why these two expressions ($r_1$ and $r_2$) are not equivalent in sympy:

```
import sympy as sp

B, V, m, q = sp.symbols('B V m q', positive = True, real = True)

r1 = (1/B)*(2*V*m/q)**(1/2)
r2 = (2*V*m/(q*B**2))**(1/2)

# returns false
r1 == r2

# returns false also
r1.simplify() == r1.simplify()
```

The only difference that I can see is that in the first case, B is raised to 1 and in the second, B is not raised to one (explicitly). I have read the `sympy` FAQ and [various questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27559172/sympy-simplification-with-square-root) which have suggested to set `real=True` and `positive=True` to deal with the square root issue, but that doesn't seem to be working here.

Anyone have any suggestions?

[image: Jupyter Notebook output showing the above]

Comment: What do `r1.simplify()` and `r2.simplify()` return?

Comment: @JustLearnedIt : .simplify() returns exactly the same thing (there is no further simplification possible).

Answer (score 0):

Aha!

I think I discovered how to check for equality,

```
r1.equals(r2)
```

Returns True (as expected)!

Thanks all...

Source: [This SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62640061/2217577)